# Alpha Blending working different on 2 PCs

Tags: c#, xna, directx, textures, alphablending

I'm currently developing a tiny window cleaning game in XNA where I draw a layer of dirt (a 2d Texture with varying alpha) above any random image. The layer of dirt should get more and more transparent the better the player cleans the window.

The code looks something like:

```cs
ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.NonPremultiplied);
// draw the dirt
ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.Draw(_currentDirt, ScreenManager.GameRectangle, Color.White);
// draw the image                
ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.Draw(_currentImage, ScreenManager.GameRectangle, Color.White);        
ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.End();
```

On one PC (equipped with a NVIDIA Quadro 1000M graphic card) the alpha blending works like a charm and the effect works as expected. Exactly the same code executed on a second PC (equipped with a AMD Radeon HD 7730M) fails to display the layer of dirt.
I tested the code also on a third PC (equipped with a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 2600). Here the effect worked as expected again.

I assume that the graphic card on the second PC is responsible for the problem, but honestly I'm not sure.
Do you any idea how I should or could change the code to run on both machines or what is going wrong here?

Thank you very much for your help.

best regards,
Thomas

Update:
Screenshot of game on one of the PCs where the alpha blending works:[image: example working]

Screenshot of game on the PC where the alpha blending does not work:[image: example not working]

Update 2:
The images are selected randomly and do not influence the effect.

In `LoadContent` I do something like:

```cs
// load the image
Texture2D _currentImage = new Sprite(ScreenManager.Content.Load<Texture2D>("anyImage"));

// create the dirt texture
int _nrPixelsDirt = ScreenManager.GameRectangle.Height * ScreenManager.GameRectangle.Width;      
Color[] _currentDirtColor = new Color[_nrPixelsDirt];

for (int i = 0; i < _currentDirtColor.Length; i++)
{
    _currentDirtColor[i] = new Color(Color.Gray.R, Color.Gray.G, Color.Gray.B, 255);
}  

Texture2D _currentDirt = new Texture2D(ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice, ScreenManager.GameRectangle.Width, 
ScreenManager.GameRectangle.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);

// set the data
_currentDirt.SetData(_currentDirtColor);
```

In `Update` I gradually decrease the alpha value of the appropriate positions in `_currentDirtColor` (clamped to Zero) and then I set the data again:

```cs
_currentDirt.SetData(_currentDirtColor);
```

The code in `Draw` looks something like:

```cs
ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.NonPremultiplied);
// draw the dirt
ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.Draw(_currentDirt, ScreenManager.GameRectangle, Color.White);
// draw the image                
ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.Draw(_currentImage, ScreenManager.GameRectangle, Color.White);        
ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.End();
```

I tried different values for the `SpritSoreMode` already: `SpriteSortMode.BackToFront` and `SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack` produce the same results on the different machines, `SpriteSortMode.Deferred` does not work on any of the three machines.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots?

Comment: Weird. I assume the photo in the background is supposed to be different between screenshots? Are you able to boil this down to some simple reproduction code that you can post?

Comment: The problem isn't `SpriteSortMode.BackToFront` is it? Shouldn't that be `Deferred`? You're not assigning depth values to these sprites in the first place. (Which would make it not the GPU, but a CPU-side difference.)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I tried different SpriteSortModes (BackToFront, FrontToBack, Deferred) but nothing changes. I updated the code snippet above.

Comment: Andrew is right. You should use Deferred, because it is the only choice not sorting by depth. You have no depth specified so yo cannot sort. But the point you missed (I hope) is that Deferred is evaluating the operations in the same order you called Draw. In this case, you draw the Dirt (transparent) before the Image (opaque) and so the Image hides the Dirt. Am I right?

Comment: Hi Petr,BlendState.Deferred and the correct order of the Draw commands solved the problem. thank you very much